# I have a method which returns JSONArray n i want to send that JSONarray to server

Tags: android

```
public JSONArray getProductCartJSON() {

    JSONArray product_array = new JSONArray();
    try {
        for (FoodItem item : getItem_list()) {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

            object.put("id", "" + item.getId());

            object.put("quantity", "" + item.getCart());
            object.put("note", "");
            product_array.put(object);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return product_array;
}
```

here am calling the above method to send to server

```
public static HttpResponse posthttp(String url2) {  
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;  
    JSONArray product_array = null;  
    URL url;  
    try {  
        url = new URL(url1);  
        Log.e(TAG, "url1 in posthttp" + url);  
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();  
        StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();  
        postDataBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode("005", "UTF-8"));  
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);  
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);  
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);  
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);  
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");  
        urlConnection.connect();  
        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();  
        jsonParam.put("t", "t");  
        jsonParam.put("m", "m");  
        jsonParam.put("n", "n");  
        jsonParam.put("a", "a");  
        jsonParam.put("p", "p");  
        jsonParam.put("e", "e"); 


        product_array = new JSONArray();  
        product_array = CartHandler.getCartHandler().getProductCartJSON();  
        jsonParam.put("pj", product_array.toString());  

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                urlConnection.getOutputStream());  
        out.write(jsonParam.toString());  
        out.close();  
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));  
        String line;  
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();  
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
            response.append(line);  
            response.append('\n');  
        }  
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {  
            System.out.println(response.toString());  
        } else {  
            System.out.println("Incorrect response code");  
        }  
        br.close();  
        urlConnection.disconnect();  

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    return httpResponse;  
}
```

Ive no problem with sending JSONObjects, but JSONArray is not able to send, its not even showing any error, am getting the details of all JSONObjects but not the JSONArray

Comment: Flagged. There are hundreds of questions, examples and tutorials of making simple HTTP connections like this.

Comment: _send the product_array to server_ ? What do you mean by that? Please provide necessary details (like if there is any program at the server end waiting for this input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method that can help you:

```
public static final String URL_CONNECTION = "https://your-url.com";
public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_FIELD = "Content-Type";
public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json";
public static final String ACCEPT_FIELD = "Accept";
public static final String ACCEPT = "application/json";
public static final String AUTHORIZATION_FIELD = "Authorization";

private String createUser() throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException,
            IOException, UnprocessableEntityException {
        //Result of the server
        String result = null;
        //Objects to connect to server
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        //URL t coonnect to server
        String url = HTTPHelper.URL_CONNECTION + PATH;
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        //Some necessary parameters that are needed in most of servers
        httpPost.addHeader(HTTPHelper.CONTENT_TYPE_FIELD,
                HTTPHelper.CONTENT_TYPE);
        httpPost.addHeader(HTTPHelper.ACCEPT_FIELD, HTTPHelper.ACCEPT);
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(sendUser().toString(), HTTP.UTF_8));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        result = HTTPHelper.getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
        return result;
}
```

In example above, when I'm doing `httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(sendUser().toString(), HTTP.UTF_8));`, I'm converting a JSON Object (`sendUser()` returns a JSON) to a String to send to server.

Comment: Thanks @Renan Banderira but my problem is how to send the JSONArray

Comment: The JSONObject is dealed with the same way. Just put toString() and send it.